# How to turn off production build and use development mode in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

First I have an app running in development mode, then I created a production build using:

```
yarn run build
```

And then served it by using:

```
serve -s build
```

Everything was working fine. But now I want to go back to development mode. How it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First delete the production code, which is `build` folder. if you're running Linux, Mac Os, so run the below command in the project directory,

`rm -rf build`

and now start the development server

`yarn run start` or `npm run start`

Comment: Still serving the files from static folder

Comment: share image of your directory structure, make sure you've deleted all things!

Comment: you need development mode, okay, that's simple. delete`build` folder and run `npm start` command. you're done!